# Ignoring errors in vectorization

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

# x = ['~', 'A', 'Sun']   # Works
x = ['~', 'Walter', 'A', 'Sun'] # Doesn't work because of Walter 
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['x'])

u = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"

df['URL'] = u + df['x']

def tbl10(u):
    html = requests.get(u).content
    tbl = pd.read_html(u)[10]
    return tbl

v = np.vectorize(tbl10)
pd.concat(v(df.URL))
```

1. How can I get pd.concat to ignore error for 'Walter'?
2. Is there a way to find out which element causes the error - after it gets ignored?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know much about `pandas` but why not `try..except` ?

Comment: ... why are you doing this this way? Why not use lists?

Comment: also there seems to be a way to tell `numpy` how to treat errors: [`numpy.seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)

Comment: @juanpa trying to learn exception handling in vectorization for large dataset.

Comment: `np.vectorize` doesn't really help performance, it is implemented as a python for-loop, basically.

Comment: @juanpa Not so. Pl refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792040)

Comment: @reservoirinvest what in that link tells you that `np.vectorize` is *not* implemented as a Python for-loop? Indeed, `np.vectorize` is never mentioned in that link. Regardless, it even says so [in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) "The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: Also, fundamentally you are dealing `object` dtype `numpy.ndarray`s, so any performance advantage of true numpy vectorization based on ufuncs implemented in compiled code is going to be significantly reduced anyway.